# Prolog - How can I output the results within the designated limits?

Tags: prolog

Thanks for visiting my question.

I'd like the program to output the numbers which demands the condition...

Ex) mid([15,2,30,4,12,3,18],10,20,L2) --> L2=[15,12,18]

Written below are my codes.

```
mid(L1,0,0,[]).
mid([L|L1],Min,Max,[L|L2]) :- L>=Min, L=<Max, mid(L1,Min,Max,L2).
min([L|L1],Min,Max,[_|L2]) :- mid(L1,Min,Max,L2).
```

If you have any good solutions, please let me know...

Answer (score 0):

```
mid([],_,_,[]).
mid([X|R], Min, Max, L) :-
    (X >= Min, X =< Max -> L = [X|L1]; L = L1), mid(R, Min, Max, L1).
```

UPDATE: Another answer based on your code. Your code results in unwanted backtracking.  You can prevent it with `!` operator:

```
mid([],_,_,[]).
mid([X|R], Min, Max, [X|L]) :-
    X >= Min, X =< Max, !, mid(R, Min, Max, L).
mid([_|R], Min, Max, L) :- mid(R, Min, Max, L).
```

Comment: The code variant using `!/0` is **not steadfast**: `mid([1,3,5,7],2,6,Xs)` succeeds with `Xs=[3,5]` which is OK, but the goals `mid([1,3,5,7],2,6,[3])`, `mid([1,3,5,7],2,6,[5])`, and `mid([1,3,5,7],2,6,[])` succeed even though they should fail!